# Git Option doesn't show in Android Studio anymore

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

I'm missing the git option in Android Studio -> VCS. One moment it was there a few minutes later it was gone and I have no clue why this happened.

Here is what I see:

[image: enable version control Integration]

And:

[image: Checkout from Version control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s mainly caused **Git Integration plugin was disabled**. You should enable the plugin:

File -> Settings -> Plugins -> serch git -> Enable Git Integration -> OK -> restart AS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have no idea why the plugin was deactivated at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do check:

- that you still have a `.git` in your project
- that the [Settings | Version Control](http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial) does show the Git integration as active (and then: "‘VCS’ –> ‘Enable Version Control Integration’.", as you show, should have Git)

Comment: There is a git folder. I've just used it to push with the command prompt. 
No there's no Settings | Version Control anymore. I also tried to reinstall android studio, but it's still missing..
I've forgotten to tell you, that I got my project from one of my fellow students  who is using macos.So I just imported the src folder into a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Check below thongs should be install-led and working.

> Git Integration Plugin
>
> GitHub  Plugin
>
> Version Control enabled from VCS.

If above things are ok and Version Control steel not visible then try below simple solution.

Search Version Control option like below:
Press

**command + shift + A in mac**

**control + shift + A in windows**

window will open then type version control and select option will appear in bottom tabs.

OR simply press **command + 9** in mac.

Comment: Command + 9 resolved my issue of disappearing Version Control option. Thanks